# iTextsharp poner caracteres en Asiatico?

Tags: c#, .net, itextsharp

Quiero generar un PDF con caracteres coreanos con español en conjunto.
Pero no sé cómo hacerlo, si alguien que me podría ayudar por favor.

Aquí mi código:

```
public ActionResult pdf()
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    Document document = new Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.LETTER,0,0,0,0);
    PdfWriter pw = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, ms);
    document.Open();

    document.Add(new Paragraph("안녕하세요, 샘플입니다(HOLA MUNDO)."));
    document.Close();

    byte[] byteStream = ms.ToArray();
    ms = new MemoryStream();
    ms.Write(byteStream, 0, byteStream.Length);
    ms.Position = 0;

    return new FileStreamResult(ms,"application/pdf");
}
```

Comment: ¿cuál es la falla en tu código?

Comment: No tiene ninguna falla, no sale las letras Koreanas, solo las letras en Español

Answer (score 1):

Estimado, para colocar caracteres asiáticos debes descargar la fuente y citarla dentro de tu codigo ITextSharp, en Stackoverflow en inglés responden a tu pregunta. En pocas palabras debes descargar fuentes CJK (Chino, Japonés y Coreano) y embeberlas a tu código.

Acá un ejemplo: [Ejemplo de fuentes orientales en ITextSharp](https://git.itextsupport.com/projects/I5JS/repos/sandbox/browse/src/main/java/sandbox/fonts/NotoExample.java)

**FUENTE: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29238674/11335797**